# How to display data in a table view that is added as IBoutlet to a view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have create a table view outlet and also drag a table view to my view.outlet is connected to table view. Now I am not able to display any data in the table view. How to do that....just want to access the table view. Thanks

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitableview-to-a-custom-uiview) link. This shows which are necessary things according to your requirment.

Comment: For this you should have searched the web: These tutorials will help you: [UITableView Tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html) [UITableView](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

To display data in the table, you must implement the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocols. You can check any tutorial about that ([this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/), for example).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement tableview data source and delegate methods.and keep in mind your class should be delegate and data source of your tableview.I mean after connecting outlet, you have to provide data source and delegate for tableview.May this link helps you:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

In order to display data in your table you need to implement tableview datasource methods. Refer to this link:
[UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

and set UITableView datasource property to your controller. If you want to perform some actions on a tableview, then you need to implement its delegate methods: Refer to this link:

[UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)